# Service locator - worth it?

Tags: .net, design-patterns, service-locator

We have a large solution (> 100 projects) and almost every type uses either a service locator (example 1) or our own dictionary of types (example 2) for instantiation.

For example we have:

```
IQuote quote = Registry.Resolve<IQuote>();
```

or

```
IQuote quote = Registry.Find<IQuote>(args);
```

The 2nd example goes off to the config file to find what concrete object to instantiate using reflection.

It makes life more difficult when following through code - because it's not clear what concrete type is being used - so we have to check the mappings many times as we're trying to learn a part of the code.  Using the above as an example pressing F12 on: `quote.DoSomething()` would take you to the interface definition.

It's also a bit more difficult to implement - we need an interface + concrete class + config mappings, when the alternative is just 1 class.

Come to think of it - I'm not aware that anything has ever been "swapped out" for another type - so although we've implemented IoC we haven't used it, or at least - very little.

So - is it actually worth it?  Have we implemented it incorrectly / too much?  Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: With regards to F12 sending you only to the interface definition and thus not being very helpful, remember that this is partly a limitation of Visual Studio and not solely DI's fault: VS *could* be improved such that it points you to the actual method being called. Obviously VS could only do this during a debugging session, and only once the object's runtime type is definitely known.

Comment: It's a good question and I would really like to read a few opinions on this, but it may be better suited for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @stakx: with VS automatic recognition of the DI class resolution could work if there were a de facto standard implementation of DI in .net (which I don't know of).

Comment: @Vlad, you misunderstood me. I am not saying that VS could parse your DI container configuration, but the debugger could inspect your `quote` variable's actual type if you were debugging in the scope where it is defined and used, and then jump to that type's definition instead of to `quote`'s static type's definitions. Limited and not a massive improvement, but might be somewhat helpful in a few circumstances.

Comment: @stakx: oh, I see. As it's done now, F12 uses static analysis, therefore it can be used when the program is not running. Perhaps some other command should be (is?) available at runtime, checking the actual runtime type? This would be valuable.

Comment: What you have there is exactly what dependency is not, and what it allows avoiding. What you have is a Factory class. It's not dependency injection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion, you don't need to work with each and every class with DI in mind. I would use the following strategy:

1. Determine the module bounds.
2. Within the same module, use concrete classes where possible.
3. For the intermodule communication, use DI where possible.

The modules should be relatively fine-grained.

There are some common places where you need to use DI, often it's replaceable data sources and (not so often) algorithms. Use the common sense to check whether something needs to be replaceable or not. Don't hesitate to throw in an early refactoring if you see something needs DI or suffers from it.

Answer (score 5):

What you guys are using is a **Service Locator** that is being considered an anti pattern,
because of:

1. All Unit Tests have to use the **Service Locator** (with DI no **DI Container** is involved)
2. You couple your whole architecture to the Service Locator (in **DI** only the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot.aspx) is using the **DI Container**)
3. You can not see the dependencies immediately of a component (with **DI** there is **Constructor Injection**)
4. Your Unit Tests become more complicated, because you have to care of your configuration, so that no other test uses another configuration erroneously (Tear Down).

http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx

Answer (score 2):

What you show is NOT a dependency injection, it is a configurable registry (which is also a pattern, but quite different). So yes, looks like a bad idea and a sort of misunderstanding.

To be able to reap benefits of some design pattern, you have to understand the benefits up-front. If you don't know them, then probably you shouldn't bother.

Comment: +1. I saw your answer after posting my comment saying the same thing.

Comment: actually, it is even worse, as it seems to be service locator antipattern. service locator used right is not a bad thing. service locator used somewhere in implementation is considered an antipattern (as seems to be the case here)

Answer (score 1):

If you unit test, dependency injection of some sort is essential for stubbing or mocking... dependencies. (Unit tests should not hit dependencies, like file system, database, network, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing the more general concept of Dependency Injection with using a DI container, which is a means to the end of implementing a very flexible form of DI. [Here](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html)'s a good article explaining DI as a concept.

In your scenario it seems to me that you could get rid of the DI container, but might still want to retain some form of DI if only for testability (as others have pointed out already). A common implementation pattern for this is implementing "broad" constructors, through which dependencies *can* be injected and which are used in unit tests. In addition there will be "narrower" constructors, which will instantiate concrete classes and pass them into the "broad" constructor. These can be used in production code until the need to actually swap around dependencies arises.

### Example:

```
class MyClass
{   
    // This will be called from production code
    public MyClass() : this(new Foo(), new Bar())
    {}        

    // This will be called from tests and can be used in production code if needed
    public MyClass(IFoo foo, IBar bar)
    {
       //do whatever you want to do in the ctor here
    }
}
```

Comment: just note: this is called constructor injection, in most cases the best way to go (besides property injection, if necessary)